# Grails 1.0.3 Upgrade Problems

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I am trying to upgrade a Grails 1.0.3 project to 1.3.7 and am having what I believe are related issues.

The old project has Hibernate xml files in conf/hibernate/Domain1.hbm.xml  I am guessing that GORM didn't exist in 1.0.3?

Do I need to essentially convert what is in the xml files into Groovy code in the Domain classes in domain/

Any other details are helpful.  Thanks.

UPDATE -

All of these changes are the result of a `org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException`  It looks like I can just move the domain files: [Relevant Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012853/grails-domain-class-mapping-collection-of-hibernate-user-types/4025847#4025847)  Is that really what I want to do though?  My understanding is that with GORM I wouldn't need to use the xml files at all.

Here is an exception

```
2011-05-29 16:43:49,616 [main] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is 

    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Duplicate class/entity mapping sportsdb.Event
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Duplicate class/entity mapping sportsdb.Event
        at org.grails.tomcat.InlineExplodedTomcatServer.doStart(InlineExplodedTomcatServer.groovy:112)
        at org.grails.tomcat.InlineExplodedTomcatServer$doStart.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at org.grails.tomcat.TomcatServer.start(TomcatServer.groovy:97)
        at grails.web.container.EmbeddableServer$start.call(Unknown Source)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:158)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy)
        at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.doCall(_GrailsSettings_groovy:280)
        at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.call(_GrailsSettings_groovy)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:149)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.call(_GrailsRun_groovy)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy.runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy:116)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy.this$4$runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:59)
        at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp:33)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
        at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
        at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
        at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Duplicate class/entity mapping sportsdb.Event
        ... 25 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Duplicate class/entity mapping sportsdb.Event
        ... 25 more
    Caused by: org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Duplicate class/entity mapping sportsdb.Event
        ... 25 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GORM certainly existed in Grails 1.0.3.

You'll probably just have to update your hibernate configuration for 1.3.7.  Take a look at the [Grails and Hibernate - Reference Documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/15.%20Grails%20and%20Hibernate.html#15.1%20Using%20Hibernate%20XML%20Mapping%20Files)

Unless you are mapping to a legacy or otherwise unusual database schema the standard GORM domain modelling is the way to go.  It's very flexible.

Comment: @JamesA - Thanks for the link and the info.  However, the hibernate xml looks fine compared to the link, so I am not sure.  Any other ideas?

Comment: @JamesA - I believe I will need to have hibernate xml AND the domain objects which will have functions to extend them.  It seems it just doesn't like that I have both.

Comment: Yes you need the mapping files in conf/hibernate and the domain classes in src/java.

Comment: @JamesA - Won't I then lose the ability to call the generated methods on the domain classes?

Comment: Do you have a sportsdb.Event class defined in your domain directory?  If you are using hibernate mappings it should be in src/groovy.  You will still be able to call GORM dynamic methods on the domain objects.

Comment: @JamesA - Yes, you are right.  If I move it over to src/groovy will I still be able to call Event.get(1)?  I read in a post that all of the Hibernate methods were 'lost' with this approach: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-1-2-0-DuplicateMappingException-td1392915.html

Comment: According to the reference documentation "Best of all, you will still be able to call all of the dynamic persistent and query methods provided by GORM!"

Comment: @JamesA - Can you point me to that location?  Thanks a lot.  Sorry for the noob questions :(

Comment: It's the same link I posted in the answer to the question for the Grails and Hibernate - Reference Documenation.

Comment: @JamesA - Oh, I misinterpreted.  Thanks for all of your help - I'll try it out.